# Jquery JSON wrap all images

Tags: jquery, dom

I have this code successfully pulling images from Behance using Jquery Json:

```
$('a.link').live('click', function () {
    h = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
    $.getJSON("http://www.behance.net/v2/projects/" + h + "?api_key=" + api + "&callback=?", function (data) {
        var project_data = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < data.project.modules.length; i++) {
            if (data.project.modules[i].type == "image") { 
                project_data += '<img src="' + data.project.modules[i].src + '" />';
            }
            if (data.project.modules[i].type == "text") {
                project_data += '<p>' + data.project.modules[i].text + '</p>';
            }
        };

        $('.portfolio-details h3').html(data.project.name);
        $('.portfolio-details div').html(project_data);
        $('.portfolio-details').fadeIn(6000);

    });
});
```

they are pulling into the page, and currently showing as individual images. But how would I wrap all the images together in this code to make a slideshow? each image text represents where the image needs to be added

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item"> each image </div>
<div class="item"> each image </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You already have slots for each image?  How do you know how many there will be?

Comment: this is just an example, not the actual code. The problem I am having is wrapping all the images together in the surrounding myCarousel and carousel-inner divs and not the text which is also being output in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you prepend/append the html you need to the `var project_data = "";` variable?

```
var project_data = '<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide"><div class="carousel-inner">';

// Loop goes here...
project_data += '<div class="item"><img src="' + data.project.modules[i].src + '"> </div>';
// more code here
// end of loop

project_data += '</div></div>';
```

**EDIT:**
Here is a simple way to approach this.

```
(function($) {
    var user = 'userNameGoesHere',
    api = 'apiKeyGoesHere', 
    project_str = "", 
    i = 0;

    var project_images, carousel;

    for(i; i <= 3; i += 1) {
        $.getJSON("http://www.behance.net/v2/users/" + user + "/projects?api_key=" + api + "&callback=?&page=" + i, function (data) {
            if ($.type(data.projects) === 'array') {
                $.each(data.projects, function(i, obj) {
                    project_str += '<a class="tips more-info link" data-placement="bottom" href="#' + obj.id + '">';
                        project_str += '<div class="span3 portfolioitem">';
                            project_str += '<img src="' + obj.covers['404'] + '">';
                            project_str += '<div class="portfolioitem-hoverinfo"> <h3>' + obj.name + '</h3> </div>';
                        project_str += '</div>';
                    project_str += '</a>';
                });
            }

            $('#portfolio-items').append(project_str);
        });
    }


    $('a.link').live('click', function () {
        var h = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');

        $.getJSON("http://www.behance.net/v2/projects/" + h + "?api_key=" + api + "&callback=?", function (data) {
            var project_data = "";

            // "data.project.modules" here throws an error on the first click... not sure why
            for (var i = 0; i < data.project.modules.length; i++) {
                if (data.project.modules[i].type == "image") { 
                    project_data += '<img src="' + data.project.modules[i].src + '">';
                }

                if (data.project.modules[i].type == "text") {
                    project_data += '<p>' + data.project.modules[i].text + '</p>';
                }
            }

            $('.portfolio-details h3').html(data.project.name);
            $('.portfolio-details div').html(project_data);
            $('.portfolio-details').fadeIn(6000);

            project_images = $('.portfolio-details').find('img');
            carousel = '<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide"> <div class="carousel-inner">';

            $.each(project_images, function(i, img) {
                carousel += '<div class="item"> <img src="' + img.src + '"> </div>';
            });

            carousel += "</div></div>";

            // Do something with the carousel - append somewhere or something
            $(document.body).prepend(carousel);
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: This is the sort of thing I need to do, but the var project_data wraps around the images and the text. How can I append the var project_data just to add the html to wrap all images?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure what exactly you're asking. Please try to refine your question. Perhaps you could provide a live example too.

Comment: So here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/matthull/88XLW/

So if you run it, the code is returning the thumbnail images wrapped in a link.
Upon clicking the images, the json returns images and text from that project. I need to just wrap all the images in that project together in the slideshow div. But as it is returning images and text i'm not sure how to just wrap the images.

Comment: One thing that I see is that the JSON you've requested doesn't return a modules array. I am talking about this line: data.project.modules[i]. If you look a the console, it throws an error. Anyway see my edit, what I've provided does what you asked for except that the modules array throws an error on the first click. I am not sure why though, perhaps you could look into the Behance api you're using.

Comment: Thank you, I feel like I have been looking at this forever! Really appreciate the help. It seems to be pulling the images twice, once into the carousel, and once below still, not sure how I would stop this. Also I need to add  <div class="item active"> to the first image slide in order to start the carousel, but not the following images.

Comment: To remove the previous images just change this line: project_images = $('.portfolio-details').find('img');   -TO-  project_images = $('.portfolio-details').find('img').remove();

Comment: Then to make the 1st one active you would do this:  $('#myCarousel').find('.item').eq(0).addClass('active');  Just make sure that this line comes after this one: $(document.body).prepend(carousel);

Comment: Thats amazing, thank you! I'm hoping you can help me with one more thing, I want to pull the fields and add it to the class surrounding the thumbnails, so I can make it filterable, however it returns: Web Design, Typography, Interaction Design with commas, how could I remove the commas?

Comment: and add the text as classes to: <a class="tips more-info link

Comment: I would recommend that you try on your own first because that's the only way to learn! We have all gone through the learning curve too. If you still can't figure it out, then post a totally new question.  I think you would agree that your initial question has been answered to its fullest, so the next thing to do would be to choose an answer as the correct response for your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `.portfolio-details` in your html, so I'll assume it's `.carousel-inner`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.project.modules.length; i++) {
        ...
    $(".portfolio-details div").eq(i).html(project_data);
}
```